# What's wrong with this induction based proof?

Tags: logic, induction, fake-proofs

Claim:
$\forall  x \in \mathbb{R^+} ,$ $ x^n=1 $ $where$ $ n\in \mathbb{N}$

Proof by induction on n:

Basis step:
  $\forall  x \in \mathbb{R^+} ,$ $ x^0=1 $

Induction Step:
Let this holds for all n$\lt n_0$
then  $x^{n_0}$=$\frac{x^{n_0-1}}{x^{n_0-2}} \times x^{n_0-1} $=$\frac{1}{1} \times1 $ $\square $

Comment: Generally speaking, if you need to use the $n-k$-th case in the induction step, then you need to prove all the cases from $n = 0$ to $n = k-1$ in the basis step. You did not prove the case $n = 1$ so you cannot be sure that $x^{n_0-2} =1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you apply it to the case that $n_0=1$ you will have a problem applying the induction hypothesis to $n_0-2=-1$, what with it not being a natural number.

Answer (score -1):

Check how to use your indcution to prove $x=1, \forall x\in R+$

If you could prove $x^{-1} = 1, \forall x\in R^+$, then you could get your conclusion, but...

Comment: why the downvote?

Comment: Please don't delete and repost an answer. You can simply undelete it.

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker It's not intended. I edited my old answer then I don't know why there are two copies posted here. So I deleted one of them. It should be due to some system bug. Btw, how could you see the deleted answer, some privilege?

Comment: Users with at least 10k rep and ♦-moderators can see deleted questions and answers.

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker Ah ok, thanks for information.